# Upload image to BigCommerce by json query

Tags: json, bigcommerce

Can somebody tell me what I am doing wrong? My JSON data is like this:

```
{"product_id":512,"image_file":"http://wwww.mydomain.com/cdn/images/9789490693718.jpg"}
```

I am posting this data by POST request to:
`https://my-demo-store.mybigcommerce.com/api/v2/products/512/images.json`

I am getting error like this:

```
[{"status":400,"message":"The JSON content provided as input is invalid. Please check your JSON syntax before trying again."}]
```

What I am doing wrong?

Kind regards
Michal

Comment: It is very hard to tell from your question what your POST data is looking like? Are you using CURL or a Rest client or something else...?

Comment: Also, are you setting the content-type header to application/json?

Comment: I use the endpoints sans the extension, so maybe try posting to `https://my-demo-store.mybigcommerce.com/api/v2/products/512/images`? 
Another issue might be that the `my-demo-store` URL doesn't work. I usually use the `store-XXXX.mybigcommerce.com` hash code version that you see when you log into the admin.

Just a suggestion, I do not know enough about the Images endpoint and uploading to be able to tell you if the contents of your package are what is expected. Also since you have product ID 512 in your endpoint, I think you don't need it in your JSON request.

Answer (score 1):

`"product_id:"` is read only. (don't include it in your JSON data) The `image_file` will link with the id used in the POST request.

Answer (score 0):

My cURL command looks like this:

curl.exe -k -s --request POST -u "shopuser:tokenkey" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{"product_id": 512,"image_file":"http://www.exhibitionsinternational.org/img/9789490693589.jpg"}' https://store-yjybvmp.mybigcommerce.com/api/v2/products/512/images.json

I don't know what I am doing wrong, I can upload new products but no images